# Switch to non-root (non-privileged) user on the command prompt of Node.js (Windows 7 - Destreamer script)

Tags: node.js

When i start a js script on Windows, on the Node.js command prompt, i have this problem:

> **ERROR: This script does not run as Admin! Please run this script with a**
>   **non-privileged user.**

How can i switch to a non-privileged user?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/171917/

Comment: Starting the node.js shell with "Run without privilege elevation" (as in yourt link) don't work.

Comment: But worked setting the UAC at the top level!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled the UAC on Windows, i restarted and enabled again the UAC (at the maximum level), so it worked for me, on the Powershell!